# Version Support - RHEL 6.10

Tags: postgresql, sonarqube, artifactory, rational-team-concert

My server administration team is going to migrate all the servers running on RHEL 6.x to 6.10. Could anyone let me know whether the following applications would be supported by RHEL 6.10?

1. SONARQube - 4.5.4 (currently running on RHEL 6.8)
2. Artifactory - 3.9.0 (currently running on RHEL 6.8)
3. Postgres - 9.4.4 (currently running on RHEL 6.8)
4. IBM RTC/RSA - 6.0.4 (currently running on RHEL 6.4)

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: If you want to know what RedHat supports, you are asking the wrong forum. If you want to know what PostgreSQL supports, the web site will tell you that 9.4 is supported. But you won't use 9.4.4, you will use 9.4.latest.

Comment: Thankx for the response. Could you please re-direct me to the correct forum for RHEL support? If you are aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

You should open a service request with RedHat to get a reliable answer.